Not able to run spark web UI on google colab
When I try to run the folowing code on google colab Im receiving empty output.
!pip install -q pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.config('spark.ui.port', '4050').getOrCreate()
!wget -qnc https://bin.equinox.io/c/4VmDzA7iaHb/ngrok-stable-linux-amd64.zip
!unzip -n -q ngrok-stable-linux-amd64.zip
get_ipython().system_raw('./ngrok http 4050 &')
!sleep 5
!curl -s http://localhost:4040/api/tunnels | grep -Po 'public_url":"(?=https)\K[^"]*'
Im trying to run a python algorithm using pyspark and also DAG visualization from Spark’s WebUI.
